# How can ONE Ruby-symbol map to MULTIPLE values?

Tags: ruby

From what I have read so far I know, that a symbol is pointing always to the same value. Unlike a string, which is mutable in Ruby. Means a string might not have the same value all the time.

But if I create a list which hashes like e.g. this one:

```
persons = [
           {first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe"}, 
           {first_name: "Lisa", last_name: "Meyer"}
          ]
```

If I now do:

```
persons[1][:first_name]
```

Then I get the correct value "Lisa".

But how does that work?

If a symbol can point to only one exact value:

**How can it differentiate between the "first_name"-symbol of the first hash and the "first_name"-symbol of the second, third ... hash?**

Comment: Your question is highly unclear. What do you mean by "a symbol is pointing always to the same value"? Ruby doesn't have pointers, so what does "point to" even mean?

Comment: _“a symbol is pointing always to the same value”_ – that has nothing to do with hashes. Such statements refer to the symbol’s _internal value_. It means that you cannot have different `:first_name` instances. The same applies to integers: you cannot have different instances of `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
persons = [
 { first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe" }, 
 { first_name: "Lisa", last_name: "Meyer"}
]
```

`persons` is an array of hashes. Arrays can be accessed by their indexes.

So, the index 0 in `persons` is `{ first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe" }`.

The index 1 in `persons` is `{ first_name: "Lisa", last_name: "Meyer"}` and so on:

```
p persons[0] # {:first_name=>"John", :last_name=>"Doe"}
p persons[1] # {:first_name=>"Lisa", :last_name=>"Meyer"}
```

Don't get confused in mutability here. It's just you're referring to the wrong data type.

If you want, you can check every hash key from `persons` and see that they have the same object_id (`first_name` and `last_name`). That's because symbols are immutables, allowing Ruby to create only one instance of them as long as your code is running:

```
persons.map { |e| e.map { |key, _| [key, key.object_id] }.to_h }
# [{:first_name=>1016988, :last_name=>1017308}, {:first_name=>1016988, :last_name=>1017308}]
```

---

As per the comment question; no, it doesn't create a new object depending on the scope, e.g.:

```
p :first_name.object_id
# 1016668

def persons
  [{ first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe"  }, 
   { first_name: "Lisa", last_name: "Meyer"}]
end

p persons.map { |e| e.map { |key, _| [key, key.object_id] }.to_h }
# [{:first_name=>1016668, :last_name=>1017308}, {:first_name=>1016668, :last_name=>1017308}]
```

`:first_name.object_id` is defined outside the scope of the `persons` method, but while inside the method, it keeps pointing to the same object.

Comment: Can one say, that it always creates a new symbol "first_name" within the scope of 0, the scope of 1 ... and so on?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The symbol `:first_name` is created only once. No matter the scope.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you select the object at index 1 of your array.

```
 {first_name: "Lisa", last_name: "Meyer"}
```

How could the value of the first_name key be different than 'Lisa'?